# Is there any authentic hadith which mentions that rewards of deeds are multiplied in Ramadan?

Tags: hadith, ramadan

In the khutbah today, the shaykh mentioned that there is no specific hadith that mentions that the rewards of deeds are multiplied in Ramadan -- except for one, which is da'eef.

He mentioned that there is a difference of opinion about multiplication of rewards in Ramadan; and the scholars who say that it multiplies, use some sort of qiyas. They use proofs such as the hadith about praying in ka'bah is 100,000 times praying anywhere else to establish that multiplication of rewards is possible.

So is there a specific, authentic hadith that mentions that rewards of deeds are multiplied in Ramadan?

Comment: http://www.alalbany.net/albany_eng_015.php

Comment: Make it an answer then :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the weak hadith that the shaykh mention, it is this:

> Salmaan may Allaah be pleased with him who narrated that the Prophet
>   sallallaahu `alayhi wa sallam ( may Allaah exalt his mention ) said:
>   "A great and blessed month has cast a shadow on you … and whoever
>   performs an obligatory act of worship in it, he will be like a person
>   who performed 70 obligatory acts of worship in other times…”

A group of scholars classified it as weak. Those include Ibn Hajar, Al-albaani and Al-'aa'thami. The reason for classifying it as Dha’eef is that its chain of narration includes ‘Ali Ibn Zayd Ibn Jud’aan, and he is a weak narrator according to the scholars.

Regarding the main question - No, there are no authentic narrations or any other Islamic text directly mentioning that the deeds are multiplied. However, some scholars made a deduction using ijtihād (not based on text) and hold a view that the deeds are multiplied. So, there is no harm in saying it because the scholars differed. However, it is not absolutely certain whether it is multiplied.

**Source:** [The multiplication of the reward of obligatory prayers in Ramadhaan](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=160215)

[Deeds multiplying in Ramadan](http://www.alalbany.net/albany_eng_015.php)